# Is samsung galaxy nexus hdpi or xhdpi

Tags: android, drawable, hdpi

I am placing images in drawable-xhdpi folder and galaxy nexus doesn't pick it up.

Is galaxy nexus HDPI or XHDPI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's XHDPI for sure (I have one). I use the drawable-xhdpi folder with no issues. Do you have other resources, in maybe the drawable-nodpi folder or something?

Comment: I have images in both drawable and drawable-xhdpi directories. In the xml file, I use, <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1"
        android:duration="100"/>

Comment: And I'm guessing you have an image1.png file in drawable-xhdpi? What makes you say it isn't picking it up exactly?

Comment: I placed images in both drawable-xhdpi and drawable folder. Galaxy nexus picks up the xhdpi, but galaxy s2, htc incredible also picks up the xhdpi, I expected drawable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I solved this simply by Refreshing the "res" folder in my structure.  Right-click on "res" folder and hit refresh.